# List fields missing in SharePoint 2013 workflow Activity window properties [Visual Studio 2012]

Tags: 2013, list, workflow, visual-studio-2012, workflow-activity

I am creating a sample workflow project in SharePoint 2013 using Visual Studio 2012. An Announcement based List instance is also created. The workflow is linked to this list.
 **In my Sequence window, i am using a LookUpSPListItem activity to get the Title and Created By property. But both the "Title" and 'CreatedBy" fields are not showing in the property window**.
Also, if i try to force add these properties, then  i get an exception in the workflow debugger window -"system.formatexception the dynamic value property was incorrectly formatted"
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get the created by, you first need to get AuthorID. After that you need to use LookupSPuser to get the name of the user from the ID.

For getting the Title, in entity type : List item of "Your list name". You should get the Title property.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 
1) AuthorID is working fine. I tried that already. But i am referencing an MSDN article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn584771(v=office.15).aspx
Title is not showing the dropdown

Comment: I tried the same thing at my end. It showing me title column. How are creating your announcement list? and what is the name of that list?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/dffd0595-40d8-4982-ab82-ca26d2e79b2d/fetch-values-from-list-in-workflow-for-sharepoint-2013-for-vs-2012?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: List is created by adding a new item (An instance of Announcement List ) in project. Name of the List - AnnouncementList.

Comment: First create that list on your site and then try.

Comment: I am creating both the list and workflow in a SharePoint App . So the list instance is created when the app is deployed. I am able to select the AuthorId from the dropdown but not Title.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16185/discussion-between-thomas-mathew-and-aanchal).

Comment: Are you using office 365 or on premise App?

Comment: on premise i.e. SharePoint Hosted app.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue and it was resolved by creating the app list based on a content type. For some reason, workflow is picking up fields only if they are part of a content type.